# d3.format SI Prefix - lowercase letters

Tags: javascript, d3.js, formatting

I'm using the wonderful d3.format throughout a large d3.js dashboard project to standardise formatting.

Two of my measures use SI-Prefixes:

```
   var my_format = d3.format(".2s");
   var my_format2 = d3.format(".3s");
```

The client wants to show a lowercase M for million.  I can clearly fix this in the code at chart level but I was wondering if anyone had a fancier solution?

Comment: Have you seen the discussion of something similar to this in the GitHub issue [#2241 *d3.format() for number abbreviations (similar to SI-prefix)*](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2241)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, patiently explain to your client what SI prefixes mean and that lower case m stands for something else...

When they say they don't care, do this:

```
var customGenerator = (f) => (n) => n > 999999 && n < 1000000000 ? d3.format(f)(n).toLowerCase() : d3.format(f)(n);
```

And use as:

```
var my_format = customGenerator(".2s");
var my_format2 = customGenerator(".3s");
```

Comment: Many thanks Mark.  I have tried Option A.  Should they persist I'm extremely grateful for you answer.